# What's an Everyday Word?

Tags: knowledge, word-property

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it an **Everyday Word**. Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Everyday Words | Not Everyday Words |
| --- | --- |
| BURDEN | TROUBLE |
| CRY | WEEP |
| GOOD | GREAT |
| HAND | FOOT |
| MICHIGAN | LOUISIANA |
| MONKEY | APE |
| NERVOUS | ANXIOUS |
| ROOSTER | CHICK |
| RUBY | AMBER |
| TIRED | WEAK |

<sub>This continues the [What is a Word/Phrase](/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](/u/463).</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that...

> **EVERYDAY** words are words that are included in the title of a song by **The Rolling Stones**:
>  "Beast of **BURDEN**"
>  "**CRY** to Me", "Fool to **CRY**"
>  "Everybody Knows About My **GOOD** Thing", "**GOOD** Time Woman", "**GOOD** Times", "**GOOD** Times, Bad Times", "Oh, Baby (We Got a **GOOD** Thing Going)"
>  "Back of my **HAND**", "**HAND** of Fate"
>  "2120 South **MICHIGAN** Avenue"
>  "**MONKEY** Man"
>  "19th **NERVOUS** Breakdown"
>  "Little Red **ROOSTER**" 
>  "**RUBY** Tuesday"
>  "Looking **TIRED"**

Comment: But why are they called "Everyday" words?

Comment: Correct! (To be precise, I used [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_songs_recorded_by_the_Rolling_Stones&oldid=923947230).) And, @FlanMan, they're called that because "everyday" is an Everyday Word.

Comment: @msh210 I still don't get why they are called "Everyday" words